# How to iterate a class?

Tags: list, class, flutter

***UPDATES***

This is my final codes just in case anyone needs it:

```
int index = -2; //I am not 100% sure why I need to start -2, but  I assume that `forEach((item){})` probably increase `index` by one, and I also increase `index` inside of the loop, so that's probably why.

    recyclable.forEach((item) {
      index++;
      if (item.title == _outputs[0]["label"]) {
        //your code for when the match is found
        //move to the detailed page to show more description
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailScreen(recyclable: recyclable[index]),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

***END OF UPDATES***

I created a class named `Recyclable`, and using the class, I created a list named `recyclable`. The list `recyclable` has a string named `title`, and I am trying to iterate that `title` to find a match with `_outputs[0]["label"]`.

To do it, I tried the following code:

```
    while (_outputs[0]["label"] != recyclable[index].title) {
      index++;
    }
```

Somehow, there was a red underline for `index`, which I have no idea why.

I also tried `for loop` as below to remove that red underline by removing `index` from my code:

```
    for (var _outputs[0]["label"] in recyclable.title) {
      index++;
    }
```

But the code seems to be completely off.

FYI, Here is my class `Recyclable`:

```
class Recyclable {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String instruction;
  final String why;
  final String
      recycle; //put either "recyclable" or "not recyclable" (This item "can be recycled")
  final String
      donate; //put either "can be donated" or "cannot be donated" (This item "can be donated")

  Recyclable(this.title, this.description, this.instruction, this.why,
      this.recycle, this.donate);
}
```

And here is the `list`:

```
List<Recyclable> recyclable = [
Recyclable('PAPERS', 'abc2', 'instruction123', 'why123', 'recyclable',
      'cannot be donated'),
  Recyclable('CLOTHING', 'abc3', 'instruction123', 'why123', 'recyclable',
      'can be donated'),
  Recyclable('CARDBOARDS', 'abc4', 'instruction123', 'why123',
      'can be recycled', 'cannot be donated'),
  Recyclable('COMPUTERS', 'abc4', 'instruction123', 'why123', 'recyclable',
      'can be donated'),
];
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.  Posting screenshots with squiggly lines is not very useful; you don't indicate what errors are given.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jamesdlin I added more information to clarify my question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @JigarPatel I added more information to clarify my question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the error was (hover your mouse cursor over the text with the red squiggly lines, or just run `dartanalyzer` manually), and you still haven't provided a minimal, complete, verifiable example that other people can use to reproduce whatever you're encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can iterate over the `recyclable` list is like this using [forEach](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) method

```
  recyclable.forEach((item){
    if(item.title == _outputs[0]["label"]){
      //your code for when the match is found
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, `forEach` is red-underlined and states that it is not defined for the type `Recyclable`.

Comment: Seems like you must have called it on `Recyclable` class by mistake. You need to call the `forEach` method on the list `recyclable`. So "recyclable" with a small "r" instead of capital "R".